# Why can't I index row by datetime index in pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetimeindex

I can't seem to index rows using datetime index with pandas. Information on my dataframe shows that the index is datetimeindex:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 223 entries, 2013-10-29 to 2017-05-29
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Unnamed: 0    223 non-null float64
company       223 non-null object
date          223 non-null object
date_conv     223 non-null object
text          223 non-null object
title         223 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(5)
memory usage: 17.2+ KB
```

But when I do this it returns 'key error'

```
df['2017-02-04']
```

Should I have index series name as "index" to make this work? Although the my df is using datetimeindex, the column name of the index is not 'index' it's 'date_conv'.

Comment: use df.loc['2017-02-04']

Comment: @run-out Ok, that worked! thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your example `'2017-02-04'` is string.
You have to refer to the row by datetime:

```
df.loc[datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-2-4', '%Y-%m-%d'),:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You CAN use a string to address a row in a DataFrame, but you need to do it using the loc property:

```
df_row = df.loc['2017-02-04']
```